# Dapper: How to cancel an async non-buffered query?

Tags: async-await, ado.net, grpc, dapper, cancellation

Using Dapper's `SqlMapper.QueryAsync<T>` method for a mix of buffered (small, predetermined in size) and non-buffered (large, potentially millions of rows in size, unable to tell in advance) queries in a `gRPC` API.

Testing the scenario when the API client dies/disconnects, the non-buffered query stays alive on the DB until it is fully executed even though the results are no longer being consumed by the calling service, which is wasting valuable DB resources.
Looking into the `QueryAsync` code, the cancellation token (which is correctly populated on API client death/disconnect) is only taken into consideration in the buffered case.

How do I make sure that the non-buffered query on the DB is correctly cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-buffered async API is currently... not fully async, because: `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` *did not exist* at the time. This will be revisited in v3, as an API break - along with async cancellation *generally*. So short answer: right now, you can't.

Comment: The question is about cancelling the database query. That requires calling DbCommand.Cancel and hoping the ADO.NET provider supports this. MySQL providers will try to open a new connection and issue a KILL for example. I'm not sure if closing the connection would work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the way I read the question, it is focusing around the CT; now, as for whether the CT should be semantically equivalent to `Cancel()` - that's a much more nuanced topic that I've been talking to the ADO.NET folks at MS about over the last few months - we've been explicitly having the conversation about whether *dapper* should hoop up the CT to `Cancel()`, vs whether the *provider* should be doing that.

Comment: Oopsy. It could be a long time before DbCommand gets a CT property. It won't be backwards compatible either. It would be faster to do this yourself BUT then DbCommand may never get a CT

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the async methods *already* take that, I believe

Comment: I see the CT [eventually cancels the command](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/4316474cdb6f3e09d0a9f10d70042215fa1fa74c/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs#L6447)

Comment: @MarcGravell @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks both. I think I understand the issue here.
The async method does indeed take the CT (as part of the `CommandDefinition`), it just doesn't do anything with it if `Buffered == false` and instead calls the `ExecuteReaderSync` method. 
I don't see a way to cancel the DbCommand, only close the connection itself.

Comment: @DaniJ exactly - because due to not having `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` when that API was built, we're creating a synchronous-based reader (after nominal async parts), which doesn't support CT; as I say: this needs the v3 changes to fix